# Run root program on login

Tags: debian, services, webserver

Apache2, SSH, and similar don't seem to work (unless restarted) upon booting, and logging in graphically to device. To make it work, I have to type `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`, and do the same for SSH. I am planning on having my device without a monitor or keyboard. I setup login automatically, made a shell script restarting the services, and put it in `~/.kde/Autostart`.

The reason that didn't work is because I need root privileges to restart a service. I need to restart this without any sort of input or monitor. How can I either allow non-root users to restart apache2, or allow root without password for this executable?

---

I also tried editing the sudoers file and adding:

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/ssh
username ALL = /etc/init.d/apache2
username ALL = /etc/init.d/ssh
```

It still says permission denied upon trying

---

Debian 8 (Jessie)

Comment: Apache, etc. should all work without having to log in or manually restart them. They do on all my machines, and I suspect almost everyone else running Jessie (or anything else, for that matter). I suggest figuring out why it doesn't work for you... Things to look at include `journalctl -b`, `/var/log/apache2/`, etc. Please feel free to ask further questions if needed to figure it out.

Comment: I suspect you've got Network Manager set bring up the network only for your user account, rather than system-wide.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the following command and it's output: `ls -l /etc/{init,rc*}.d/*ssh*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to make echo enter the password (as the only issue was that I wouldn't have a keyboard).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "password\n" | sudo -S command --flag argument
```

the `-e` enables backslash escape, and the sudo `-S` enables STD input (so the input from the echo, pipelined). According to the manual, `-S` inputs need to end with the `\n` escape character

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `sudo` with `nopasswd` for the command you are running. *BUT* to me it looks like you are trying to create a workaround for a deeper problem which you probably should address.

Comment: Yes, I tried something similar. I edited question to add that in. Please avoid posting these kind of posts in answers, as it will fit more in comments, once you have sufficient rep.